# reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that void conforms to using mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I want to throw an Exception when running a void method

```
when(booking.validate(any())).thenThrow(BookingException.builder().build());
```

but I have a compilation error:

```
Required type: T
Provided: void
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that void conforms to T
```

Answer (score 135, accepted):

For **void** methods, I think you need to use the `doThrow` syntax.

So in your case it would be:

```java
doThrow(BookingException.builder().build())
      .when(booking)
      .validate(any());
```

Comment: God imagine the man-years saved if this mockito error simply provided this as a hint!  I hate java more and more...

Comment: @AdamHughes sadly it's a mismatch in signatures and can not be hinted more than it already does. Excerpt of the java-doc of the when method: `For stubbing void methods with throwables see: doThrow(Throwable...)`

Comment: `reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that void conforms to T` could just end with `... did you mean doThrow()` ?

Comment: I did not try but by its name didn't `doThrow` throws and exception ? I prefer M-sAnNan method with `doNothing().when(mockedService).sendReportingLogs(null);` (answer below at this time but here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68708141/11159476).

Comment: The question was asking about throwing an exception for a method call of a mock. With all due respect, that answer does not address that.

Answer (score 32):

I Figured out the right syntax.

```
Service mockedService = new DefaultServie();
doNothing().when(mockedService).sendReportingLogs(null);
```

Hope this answers the questions

Comment: This tripped me up, and this helped. Thanks.

Comment: bruh, this should just be in the document instead of what they have now

Answer (score 3):

Just complementing @Shane 's comment, which was a life saver but not very clear.

Example on how to throw PersistenceException from a repository method:

```
doThrow(new PersistenceException())
            .when(outboxRepository)
            .delete(isA(WorkersEphemeralOutboxEntry.class));
```

I find this especially helpful when you have overloaded methods and the compiler cannot figure out which one to call with any() and any(Class.class) gives you compiling error.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Use <code>doThrow()</code> when you want to stub the void method with an exception.
 * <p>
 * Stubbing voids requires different approach from {@link Mockito#when(Object)} because the compiler
 * does not like void methods inside brackets...
 * <p>
 * Example:
 *
 * <pre class="code"><code class="java">
 *   doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
 * </code></pre>
 *
 * @param toBeThrown to be thrown when the stubbed method is called
 * @return stubber - to select a method for stubbing
 */
@CheckReturnValue
public static Stubber doThrow(Throwable... toBeThrown) {
    return MOCKITO_CORE.stubber().doThrow(toBeThrown);
}
```

Comment: While doThrow is the correction function to handle the problem, please provide also some code to show how to use it, so you provide a concrete answer to the question.